# Merge two lists in Java and sort them using Object property and another condition

Tags: java

I have two lists `List<Person> list1 = new ArrayList(), list2 = new ArrayList();` (Not the same size), of the class `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + '}';
    }

}
```

I want to create a new list using `list1` and `list2` sorted by `age` (descending), but I also another condition that is better explained with an example:

```
//L1 = from list1, L2 = from list2
//looping trough the new list
Person{name=Alec L1, age=75}
Person{name=Menard L1, age=50} //Bob should be here
Person{name=Bob L2, age=50}
```

He should, because his age is equal to Menard, Alec is from L1 and two Person from L1 can't be one after another is this kind of situation happens.

A complete list should look like this:

```
Person{name=Giant L2, age=100}
Person{name=Derp L1, age=50}
Person{name=John L2, age=50}
Person{name=Menard L1, age=44}
Person{name=Lili L2, age=44}
Person{name=Lili L1, age=44}
Person{name=Menard L2, age=44}
Person{name=Bob L1, age=22}
Person{name=Alec L2, age=21}
Person{name=Alec L1, age=21}
Person{name=Herp L2, age=21}
Person{name=Herp L1, age=21}
Person{name=Alice L1, age=12}
Person{name=Little L2, age=5}
```

Here is my complete code to achieve this result:

```
    List<Person> list1 = new ArrayList(), list2 = new ArrayList();

    list1.add(new Person("Derp L1", 50));
    list1.add(new Person("Alec L1", 21));
    list1.add(new Person("Herp L1", 21));
    list1.add(new Person("Menard L1", 44));
    list1.add(new Person("Lili L1", 44));
    list1.add(new Person("Alice L1", 12));
    list1.add(new Person("Bob L1", 22));

    Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Person object1, final Person object2) {
            return object2.getAge()-object1.getAge();
        }
    });


    list2.add(new Person("Little L2", 5));
    list2.add(new Person("Lili L2", 44));
    list2.add(new Person("Alec L2", 21));
    list2.add(new Person("Herp L2", 21));
    list2.add(new Person("Menard L2", 44));
    list2.add(new Person("Giant L2", 100));
    list2.add(new Person("John L2", 50));


    Collections.sort(list2, new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Person object1, final Person object2) {
            return object2.getAge()-object1.getAge();
        }
    });
    List<Person> allList = new ArrayList();
    int l1 = 0, l2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size()+list2.size(); i++)
        if (l1 < list1.size() && l2 < list2.size())
            if (list1.get(l1).getAge() > list2.get(l2).getAge())
                allList.add(list1.get(l1++));
            else if (list1.get(l1).getAge() < list2.get(l2).getAge())
                allList.add(list2.get(l2++));
            else if (allList.size() > 0)
            {
                if (list1.get(l1).getName().contains("L1") == allList.get(allList.size()-1).getName().contains("L1"))
                    allList.add(list2.get(l2++));
                else
                    allList.add(list1.get(l1++));
            }
            else
                allList.add(list1.get(l1++));
        else if (list1.size() == l1)
            allList.add(list2.get(l2++));
        else
            allList.add(list1.get(l1++));

    for (Person person : allList)
        System.out.println(person.toString());
```

But, is there another way to do it? More elegant code or using some built in Java class?

Comment: What happens if you have in List1, 50, 40 30 , and in List2 50 45 42?

Comment: L1-50 first, L2-50 next, then, L2-45, L2-42,  L1-40 and L1-30

Comment: And yet you have `Person{name=Herp L1, age=21}` followed by `Person{name=Alice L1, age=12}` in your expected list... care to update?

Comment: I fail to see where the problem is. 12 is less than 21 and no one from L2 is in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem statement is not very clear.  As I understand it, you want to have a combined sorted list but interleave elements from list1 and list2 whenever the age is the same.

Here's a simple implementation of that logic.  I used java 8 streams to sort lists and put them in `ArrayDeque`s.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;

static<T> List<T> interleaveSort(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Comparator<T> cmp) {
    // sort the lists and set them up as queues
    Deque<T> x = list1.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
    Deque<T> y = list2.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(x.size() + y.size());

    while (!x.isEmpty() && !y.isEmpty()) {
        if (cmp.compare(x.peek(), y.peek()) > 0) {
            result.add(y.poll());
        } else {
            // whenever we pick from X, swap queues so next time we will favor the other list
            result.add(x.poll());
            Deque<T> t = x;
            x = y;
            y = t;
        }
    }
    // since the while loop terminates when one of the queues is empty
    // we should add the left-over elements
    result.addAll(x);
    result.addAll(y);

    return result;
}
```

Then, in your main method:

```
List<Person> allList=interleaveSort(list1, list2, comparing(Person::getAge).reversed());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get: invalid method reference: "non-static method getAge() cannot be referenced from a static context" when I call interleaveSort.

Comment: I had to do : `List<Person> combo = interleaveSort(list1, list2, Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed());` and then your code worked.

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo.  I did a static include of `comparingInt` but used `comparing`.  static include is right and the code is wrong.  It's actually better to do `comparingInt(Person::getAge)`

Answer (score -1):

You can do `list1.addAll(list2)` and then sort `list1` which now contains both lists

Comment: If you try your proposed code, it would give something like this:
Person{name=Giant L2, age=100}
Person{name=Derp L1, age=50}
Person{name=John L2, age=50}
Person{name=Menard L1, age=44}
Person{name=Lili L1, age=44}
Person{name=Lili L2, age=44}
Person{name=Menard L2, age=44}
Person{name=Bob L1, age=22}
Person{name=Alec L1, age=21}
Person{name=Herp L1, age=21}
Person{name=Alec L2, age=21}
Person{name=Herp L2, age=21}
Person{name=Alice L1, age=12}
Person{name=Little L2, age=5}
And it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: not if you call the sort after merging the list as suggested here

Comment: I don't know if it is only me, but doing : `list1.addAll(list2);` then      `Collections.sort(list1, (final Person object1, final Person object2) -> object2.getAge()-object1.getAge());` give me the same result as my previous comment

Comment: Please add some more context to your post. For example, explain why your solution is better, explain the reasoning behind your solution, etc.